# Why is a Guid parameter arriving as default in ASP method?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id}")]
    public Task<ActionResult<Model?>> Get(
        Guid id)
    {
        return ReadModel(id);
    }
```

In the watch, if I inspect `Request.Path` I can see that the path is `/api/Model/798f2724-c01b-4836-9603-5b64acaed464`, but when I inspect `id` it has a value of `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`

I'm calling this from postman with the following URL `https://localhost:7685/api/Model/798f2724-c01b-4836-9603-5b64acaed464`

I've also tried adding this in the method just to see if something was off about the Guid, but this object is created correctly:

```
Guid temp = new Guid("798f2724-c01b-4836-9603-5b64acaed464");
```

Am I supposed to do something to tell asp how to parse a guid?

Comment: How are your routes configured on startup?

Comment: I just call this: builder.Services.AddControllers();

This seemed to work fine when I was taking a string id instead of a guid

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Core? Or is this the old ASP.NET on .NET Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be working properly,recheck id if it is valid one more time. I would add an type validation to the  action attribute and add async since you are using a task

```
        [HttpGet("{id:Guid}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Model?>> Get(Guid id)
```

or if you don't have any async code inside of the action

```
        [HttpGet("{id:Guid}")]
        public ActionResult<Model?> Get(Guid id)
```